# CSS quirk with IE8, any suggestions?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer-8

Why must IE be so difficult?

Building site on ASP.NET MVC platform. Email page has a border around the form (set by div). IE makes a mess of things.

Screenshot of page rendered in IE8:
[image: Internet Exploder]

Screenshot of page rendered in Firefox 3.6:
[image: Firefox]

Screenshot of page rendered in Chrome 8:
[image: Chrome]

I think I have narrowed down the problem, here is the code of the email page (the css 'hack' was my failed attempt at hiding it):

```
#CallBackForm
{
    margin-top:65px;
    padding:10px 10px 15px 10px;
    background-color:#eef7ff;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    height:260px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
/** html .centerform
{
    background-color:white!important;
    border:1px solid white!important;
    display:none;
    visibility:hidden;
    height:0;
}*/
.centerform
{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:360px;
}
```

---

```
<div id="CallBackForm">
    <div class="centerform">
    <p>Please fill out the following form and Perri Building will contact you shortly!</p>
    <% using (Html.BeginForm("CallBack","Home", FormMethod.Post, new {@id="CallBack"})) {%>
        <%= Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
            <div class="grid_3">
                <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.FName) %>
            </div>
            <div class="grid_6">
                <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FName) %><%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FName) %>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="grid_3">
                <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.LName)%>
            </div>
            <div class="grid_6">
                <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LName)%><%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LName)%>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="grid_3">
                <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.Phone)%>
            </div>
            <div class="grid_6">
                <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Phone)%><%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone)%>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="grid_9">
                <%= Html.GenerateCaptcha() %>
            </div>
            <div class="grid_8" style="text-align:right;"><input type="submit" value="Send" /></div>
    <% } %>
    </div>
</div>
```

I found out if I put text here in the code, I'd get these results:

```
<div id="CallBackForm">
    <div class="centerform">
    <% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
       //.....
    <% } %>
    test1
    </div>
    test2
</div>
test3
```

[image: Debug]

So for some reason IE assumes I want every div inside of container `CallBackForm` to have the same style applied to it.

Any suggestions?

## EDIT:

It is something with the form generated by MVC. I commented out the contents of the form, double box in IE still. Commenting out the entire form (between the `<% %>` tags) results in one box in all browsers. Will continue experimenting.

### CSS:

```
@import 'reset.css';
@import 'text.css';
@import '960_24_col.css';

/* Styles for validation helpers
-----------------------------------------------------------*/
.field-validation-error
{
    color: #ff0000;
}

.field-validation-valid
{
    display: none;
}

.input-validation-error
{
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;
    background-color: #ffeeee;
}

.validation-summary-errors
{
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ff0000;
}

.validation-summary-valid
{
    display: none;
}

/* Styles for recaptcha
-----------------------------------------------------------*/

.recaptchatable .recaptcha_image_cell, #recaptcha_table {
   background-color:transparent !important; /*reCaptcha widget background color*/
 }

 #recaptcha_table {
   border-color: transparent !important; /*reCaptcha widget border color*/
 }

 #recaptcha_response_field {
   border-color: #abadb3 !important; /*Text input field border color*/
   background-color: white !important; /*Text input field background color*/
}

#recaptcha_logo , #recaptcha_tagline
{
    display:none !important;
}

/* Styles for front page layout
-----------------------------------------------------------*/

#top_border
{
    height:1px;
    margin-bottom:2px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #42699d;
}
#bottom_border
{
    height:1px;
    margin: 2px 0px 2px 0px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #42699d;
}
#layout_main 
{
    margin-top:15px;
}
#top_nav
{
    display:block;
    height:54px;
}
#side_ads 
{
    margin-left:-10px;
}
#side_ads .first
{
    margin-top:3px;
    margin-bottom:2px;
}
#side_ads .second 
{
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
#side_ads .third
{
    margin-top:2px;
}
#testimonials 
{
    margin-left:5px;
    background-image: url("images/page_curl.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display:block;
    height:338px;
}
#testimonials .content
{
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-top:30px;
    width:225px;
}
#testimonials h2
{
   font-weight:bold;
   font-size:14px;
}
#testimonials p.body
{
    display:block;
    height:175px;
}
#testimonials p.by
{
    font-style:italic;
    text-align:right;
    width:200px;
}
#testimonials .buttons 
{
    margin-top:110px;
}
#bottom_links
{
    margin-top:10px;
    text-align:center;
}
#bottom_links p
{
    margin:0px;
    color:#9a081b;
}
#bottom_links a
{
    color:#42699d;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#bottom_links a:hover
{
    border-bottom:1px solid #42699d;
}

/* Styles Product Pages
-----------------------------------------------------------*/

#side_img 
{
    margin-left:-10px;
    margin-top:3px;
}
#product_content
{
    padding:0px 5px 5px 5px;
    display:block;
    width:639px;
    height:185px;
    background-color:#dcd2c3;
    border:1px solid black;
}
#product_content h2
{
    margin-bottom:0px;  
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#970016;
    font-size:24px;
}
#product_content p
{
    text-align:justify;
    margin-top:0px;
    width: 515px;
    font-size:12px;
}
#product_content #content_image 
{
    position:relative;
    top:58px;
    float:right;
    display:block;
    width:112px;
    height:92px;
}

/* Styles Mailing Pages
-----------------------------------------------------------*/

#mail_ads
{

}
#mail_ads .first
{
    margin-top:3px;
    margin-bottom:2px;
}
#mail_ads .second 
{
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
#mail_ads .third
{
    margin-top:2px;
}
/*#mail_content 
{
    display:block;

}*/

#CallBackForm
{
    margin-top:65px;
    padding:10px 10px 15px 10px;
    background-color:#eef7ff;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    height:260px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.centerform
{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:360px;
}
```

HTML Source (as rendered by IE):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>


    Request a Callback


</title>
    <link href="/Content/Site.css" type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" />



</head>
<body>
    <form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="CallBack" id="aspnetForm">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwULLTEwNTM3NTY3MTNkZIccQzHp+0a2l4J4rJdeDfOAYoCO" />
</div>

    <div class="container_24" id="layout_main">
        <div class="grid_10" id="logo">
            <a href="/"><img alt="Perri Building &amp;amp; Renovations" src="/Content/images/logo.png" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="grid_14" id="top_nav">
            Navigation stuff goes here
        </div>
        <div class="clear">
        </div>
        <div class="grid_24" id="top_border"></div>

    <div class="grid_7" id="mail_ads">
        <a href="/Product/Windows"><img alt="Perri Windows" class="first" src="/Content/images/windows_ad.jpg" /></a>
        <a href="/Product/Siding"><img alt="Perri Siding" class="second" src="/Content/images/siding_ad.jpg" /></a>
        <a href="/Product/Roofing"><img alt="Perri Roofing" class="third" src="/Content/images/roofing_ad.jpg" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="grid_12" id="mail_content">

    <div id="CallBackForm">
        <div class="centerform">
        <p>Please fill out the following form and Perri Building will contact you shortly!</p>
        <form action="/Home/CallBack" method="post">
                <div class="grid_3">
                    <label for="FName">First Name:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="grid_6">
                    <input id="FName" name="FName" type="text" value="" />
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <div class="grid_3">
                    <label for="LName">Last Name:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="grid_6">
                    <input id="LName" name="LName" type="text" value="" />
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <div class="grid_3">
                    <label for="Phone">Phone Number:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="grid_6">
                    <input id="Phone" name="Phone" type="text" value="" />
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <div class="grid_9">
                    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        var RecaptchaOptions = {
            theme : 'clean',
            tabindex : 0
        };

</script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6Lc608ASAAAAAPi_2PD2wK1P_o3r2daH0j1B26Eu"> 

</script><noscript>
        <iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=6Lc608ASAAAAAPi_2PD2wK1P_o3r2daH0j1B26Eu" width="500" height="300" frameborder="0">

        </iframe><br /><textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea><input name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge" type="hidden" />
</noscript>
                </div>
                <div class="grid_8" style="text-align:right;"><input type="submit" value="Send" /></div>
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>


<div class="grid_24" id="bottom_border">
</div>
<div class="grid_8">
    <a href="/Product/Windows"><img alt="Perri Windows" src="/Content/images/windows.jpg" /></a>
</div>
<div class="grid_8">
    <a href="/Product/Roofing"><img alt="Perri Roofing" src="/Content/images/roofing.jpg" /></a>
</div>
<div class="grid_8">
    <a href="/Product/Siding"><img alt="Perri Siding" src="/Content/images/siding.jpg" /></a>
</div>
<div class="clear" style="margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="grid_8">
    <a href="/"><img alt="Perri Insulation" src="/Content/images/insulation.jpg" /></a>
</div>
<div class="grid_8">
    <a href="/"><img alt="Perri Gutters" src="/Content/images/gutters.jpg" /></a>
</div>
<div class="grid_8">
    <a href="/"><img alt="Perri Patio Doors" src="/Content/images/patio.jpg" /></a>
</div>
<div class="clear">
</div>

        <div class="grid_14 push_5" id="bottom_links">
            <p><a href="/Product/Windows">Windows</a> | <a href="/Product/Roofing">Roofing</a> | <a href="/Product/Siding">Siding</a> | <a href="#">Insulation</a> | <a href="#">Gutters &amp; Gutter Protection</a> | <a href="#">Patio Doors</a></p>
            <p><a href="#">Kitchens</a> | <a href="#">Bathrooms</a> | <a href="#">Additions</a> | <a href="#">Decks</a> | <a href="#">Doors</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Image composite from IE Dev tools:

[image: Debug2]

Comment: Could you validate your html just to make sure there's no unclosed div tags?

Comment: Copy/pasting the source from IE passes validation as XHTML 1.0 Transitional. Used http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: You'd definitely get an answer much faster if you could provide a live page. I can see it's currently hosted on your machine, but surely you could put a snapshot of rendered HTML online somewhere?

Comment: Your wish is granted. Should have done that first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It must be this

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("CallBack","Home", FormMethod.Post, new {@id="CallBack"})) {%>
```

You are creating and rendering another form named CallBackForm here (besides the `<div>` that you already have at `<div id="CallBackForm">`). Please check it out.

Comment: The `<div class="clear"></div>` is part of the 960.gs layout system. As suggested, I removed them as well as the useless 'hack'. Same result.

Comment: No, something is definitely wrong there with your code and somehow Firefox and Chrome still manage to display it right. I haven't have problems with IE with regards to rendering since I started to use IE8. Before there were many problems but most of those are gone with IE8.

Comment: Why do you have * html .centerform there?

Comment: @mare - Testing only, I was attempting to use an IE8-only css hack (the `* html` before the class). It didn't work so I removed it after posting the question. Also, check the new edit at the bottom of my post.

Comment: Also pull out IE's dev toolbar (F12) and point it's selector pointer to the second rectangle and inspect where does it get its CSS layout. Btw if you are only showing us a part of your CSS file, it could be some other classes/IDs interfering.

Comment: Where exactly on the tool can I find where it is pulling from? Check latest edit, full CSS + image of what I got for rectangles on the dev tool.

Comment: You should have tabs HTML, CSS, Script and Profiler. On the HTML tab there is a pointer button that says "Select element by click". Use this to select rendered elements on the page. On the right site there will be a CSS styles breakdown.

Comment: @mare - As for your edit, I tried just writing out the `<form>` code, instead of having it generated. Same result. I removed all the ID's from the form. Check latest edit.

Comment: Please try changing {@id="CallBack"} to {@id="MyCallback"}

Comment: No change, I removed the ID all together. It was originally there just to test to see if there was some sort of name confusion.

Comment: What is this doing in there <form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="CallBack" id="aspnetForm"> <div> <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwULLTEwNTM3NTY3MTNkZIccQzHp+0a2l4J4rJdeDfOAYoCO" /> </div>

Comment: No, that is generated by `<form id="form1" runat="server">` in the main master page for the ASP.NET MVC project. It is required for the system to run.

Comment: No form in Site.master is required for MVC sites and apps to work. You will have to take a look at that. Especially not one with runat="server" attribute. It certainly doesn't come with out of the box VS MVC templates.

Comment: @Mare - winner. I remember why that extra form was there; It was originally generated when I created the project. When I changed the type of master page around to allow html/url extensions, I forgot to remove it. Removing this form doesn't impact compilation anymore, and furthermore the phantom box disappears from IE. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a div tag to provide the border can you use the Fieldset tag? You will be able to style the fieldset border however you want and the Fieldset tag would make more "semantic" senese here and it is distinct from any further divs.

Something like:

```
<fieldset class="CallBackForm">     
   <div class="centerform">     
       <p>Please fill out the following form and Perri Building will contact you shortly!</p>  
   //Form Stuff  
   </div> 
</fieldset>
```

And change your CSS to:

```
fieldset.CallBackForm
{
   /*Your Style*/
}
```

Comment: yeah, fieldset would be nice but now we have to get to the bottom of this. ;)

Comment: Sure, will try this out. It will replace the outer DIV with the ID, correct?

Comment: Either way, replacing the outer or inner DIV with fieldset still has the phantom box in IE.